# How to access an object in an array of objects passed through a prop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a v-select dropdown which just contains the scores in the teamData object. When I try to render it to the component form the parent nothing shows up, what needs to be added for the list to populate with just the teamNames parameter.

Parent.vue File

```
var teamData = [
  {
    teamName: "Buccaneers",
    score: 0,

  },
  {
    teamName: "Seahawks",
    score: 0,
  
  },
  {
    teamName: "Patriots",
    score: 0,

  },
  {
    teamName: "49ers",
    score: 0,

  }
]

<score-component :teamData="Team Data"> </score-component>
```

Component.vue File

```
<template>
<v-select :items="teamData.score"></v-select>
</template>
<script>
export default{
props:["teamData"]
data: () => ({

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The teamData array must be present on data() section in parent component.

Then you pass it to the :teamData property on score-component.

Take a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/festive-lumiere-rp1jk2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Also the official docs has a good section describing on how to work with components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: The properties still cant be accessed though, im trying for just the team names but it comes up as blank on the codesandbox example.

Comment: @espressojava  in component file the option line:       <option v-for="team in teamData" :key="team.teamName">{{ team.teamName }}</option>

Comment: Right, i need it to work for the vuetify library as it uses <v-select> but i think i found a workaround for now though.